# Does Anakin's Lightsaber Use Electrum?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

Anakin's lightsaber has gold-like pieces on it. Usually, this is Electrum when it comes to lightsabers (see Sidious and Windu's). Electrum was reserved for high-ranking Jedi/Members of the Council.

### Sidious's Lightsaber

[image: Image of Darth Sidious's lightsaber hilt]

### Windu's Lightsaber

[image: Image of Mace Windu's lightsaber hilt]

### Anakin's Lightsaber (Suspected Electrum Circled For Reference)

[image: Image of Anakin Skywalker's lightsaber hilt]

Comment: I'm fairly certain that Sidious was not on the Jedi council either.

Comment: Well yes, but did he follow the council's rules? I mean, he was the Sith Lord...

Answer (score 4):

**Unlikely.** The [Star Wars: The Complete Visual Dictionary](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Complete_Visual_Dictionary,_New_Edition) notes (regarding Windu's Lightsaber);

> Electrum finish **for Council senior only**.

Anakin wasn't on the Jedi Council when he created his lightsaber (in 22BBY), and even if he altered it after joining them (in 19BBY) he certainly wouldn't have been considered a 'Council senior'.

While it's *possible* that the activation button was plated with electrum, I think we can safely say that that would be seen as massively presumptuous for a mere Jedi Knight.

Comment: I don't disagree, I'm just gonna add that Anakin almost always disobeyed the council, so Electrum isn't too far from his personality.

Comment: @MahmoudSalaheddine - Anakin seems pretty loyal. Aside from having a bit of a tantrum and a tendency to go off half-cocked, when else did he disobey them?

Comment: Obi-Wan's lightsaber circa the Clone Wars had a near-identical polished-gold-colored design on the activation button and on the choke section: https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/d/d5/KenobiEpIIISaber-MR.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20100618033432 . By 9BBY those areas had gained a patina: https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/f/f7/Obi-WanKenobi%27sThirdLightsaberPropKenobi.png/revision/latest?cb=20220702153753 . Does that lend any credence to it just being made of brass or some similar material, since the OG Obi-Wan hilt had brass and copper parts?

Answer (score -2):

No.

Electrum is not a metal. It is a crystal, which can be used as a finish (according to its [Wookiepedia article](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Electrum?so=search)). The difference between the lightsabers can be seen in the sheen. Windu's, which has this finish, is shiny. The "suspected electrum" on Anakin's has no such shine. Anakin's lightsaber is dull in comparison.
In addition, the Wookiepedia articles for Windu's and Sidious' lightsabers specify the presence of electrum, while the one for Anakin's does not.

Comment: Thats the new canon definition of electrum. However this would fall under the Legends definition for it, a rare metal, as these lightsabers were designed prior to 2015 when the new definition was given.

Comment: @knightwatch "Canon definition of electrum"?  Electrum is not a fictional material!  It's just an archaic name for a gold alloy.  Fourteen-karat gold is "electrum."

Comment: @buss Yes but in the new Disney Star Wars canon Electrum is a crystal not an alloy. So it is a fictional material now.

Comment: @knightwatch this question was not asked pre-2015, so I answered accordingly. Also, even ignoring the first reason in my answer, the Wookiepedia sources tell us specifically that Sidious and Windu both had electrum on theirs. It only says alloy metals and carbon composites for Anakin's.